# 502 Bad Gateway Error after Axios requests

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, axios, amazon-elb

I have a NodeJS API and an AWS Load Balancer.

I need to process a credit card payment, and to do this I make 3 requests to my credit card provider with Axios.

On localhost, everything works fine, but when I put it online on AWS, I get 502 error. The payment and all internal functions is processed normally, but I can't get the response from the server.

The requests take around 7 seconds to complete.

Are there something special to do to get it working?

Tell me if you need a specific information.

Comment: Have you checked your security groups to be sure you have the port(s) open to make calls out? Also, be sure the NACL allows it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I checked the security groups and NACL. I enabled all traffic to test and it continue to return the 502. The calls are made fine. But it seems that the load balancer lost the connection on the payment flow and can't send a response, so I get 502. But the payment is processed ok